# C# Drawing function is looping

Tags: c#, draw

I have a function where I check if a letter is in word-hangman game. If it's not, I increase the error by 1. What is being draw depends on error.

My first problem is that when the error becomes 1, the function becomes looped (I created messagebox just for test, and messagebox is showing up all the time).

My second problem is that nothing is actually drawn. I have this code in class and I want it to draw  to a panel (I having multiple panels).

```
public void preveri()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < posamezne_crke.Length; i++)  
    {
        velika_crka = Char.ToUpper(posamezne_crke[i]).ToString();   
        if(tekst[i].Text == "_")
        {
            if (crka == velika_crka) 
            {
                 tekst[i].Text = crka; 
                 break;
            }
            else
            {
                napaka++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    form1.panel3_vislice.Paint += Form1_Paint; //writed here,beacouse if its on top panel3     value is null
}

public void Form1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (napaka >= 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(napaka.ToString() + "a");  //just for testing
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 2), 85, 190, 210, 190);
    }
    if (napaka >= 2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(napaka.ToString() + "s"); //just for testing
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 2), 148, 190, 148, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your variable/method names are essentially gibberish to us. I'd recommend translating them for the purposes of this post so that it's easier to understand what you're doing in your code.

Comment: What is the first value of napaka? 0?

Comment: If the message box is shown on top of the form, it invalidates the area, causing the `Paint` event to be raised as soon as you move/close it. Use `Debug.WriteLine()` and watch the "Output" window in Visual Studio instead.

Comment: tnw, preveri = check, posamezne crke = individual letters, velika crka = capital letter, tekst = text, crka = letter, napaka is Error, if that helps

Comment: Just a wild guess, are you using coordinates relative to the _form_ rather than to the _panel_? Try `e.Graphics.DrawLine(..., 0, 0, 100, 100);`.

Comment: public char[] posamezne_crke;
public string crka;                                                      and tekst is array labels

Comment: If you `preveri()` more than once (I can imagine this would be realistic for a "check" method), the `Form1_Paint` event handler will be attached to the `Paint` event over and over, causing it to be called multiple times.

Comment: preveri() is trigered only when is caled only when i click button

Comment: you realize every time you click that button and call preveri you are adding another paint event handler.  You only need to add it once.

Comment: Tried that but hen panel3 value is null,how do i fix that then?

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to the Paint event just once, during initialization, not every time you check a letter. To force a re-paint, call the Invalidate() method on the panel.

Comment: Tried that but hen panel3 value is null,how do i fix that then?

Comment: Make sure it is after the call to InitializeComponent()

Comment: Moved it to function which excutes only once but drawing is still looped and whats draw now just blinks all the time